# How to fetch element from json in browser console and write it if condition is true

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am looking for solution how to fetch data from vimeo url json and write it if condition is true. For example i have range of videos id so i want get json variable for example author: someauthor and then check for every in loop if author in json == my author. IF true then write iframe in document. Anyone know how to do it?

```js
for (i = 330463512; i < 330463516; i++) {

    fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)

    if (json.element == "200") {
        document.write(`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}" width="640" height="640" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
    fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
```

In the first `.then` you're catching the return of the fetch, which is a promise and then executing the function `.json()` that returns another promise. So you should get this return in the next `.then` and use it to log and to write inside of it. What you're doing now is using outside of the scope. You should use something like this:

```
    for (i = 330463512; i < 330463516; i++) {

        fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (json) => {
                console.log(json);
                if (json.element == "200") {
                    document.write(`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}" width="640" height="640" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`);
                }   
            }
        )

    }
```

Note that you need to use the variable json inside of the second `.then` to be in the scope that you want.

Comment: in ```fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/${i}')``` there is 404? What's wrong with ${i} I have no idea.

Comment: That 404 means that the video is not there in the server. Take a look: https://httpstatuses.com/404